# How to chain async and non-async functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I have a synchronous function that calls another synchronous function that contains an async call. As shown below:

```js
func alpha(){
   beta(); //sync
   charlie(); //sync but contains an async call
   delta(); // want this to only run after charlie() is done.
}

func charlie(){
   // do some stuff

   //Make async call
   firebase.database.ref.once().then( () =>{
       // Do some async stuff
       // Only after this stuff is done do I want Charlie() to run
   });  

}
```

What's the best way to change Alpha() so that Charlie only run after Beta?

I was thinking of doing this:

```js
async func alpha(){
   beta(); //sync
   await charlie()
   delta();
}

func charlie(){
   return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
   // do some stuff

   //Make async call
   firebase.database.ref.once().then( () =>{
       // Do some async stuff
       setReactHook1(my_data); //react hook state update
       // Only after this stuff is done do I want Charlie() to run
       resolve();
   });  
 });
}

func delta(){
  if(some condition that only applies somtimes){
     setReactHook1(new_data); //overwrite the data that Charlie stored.
   }
}
```

For what it's worth, I'm working with React, and `charlie()` makes a `useState` update and I want to make sure `delta()` only runs after the `useState` is done, which I think you cannot guarantee with Hooks.

Comment: `charlie().then(() => delta())`, also your `new Promise` is redundant.. Just make sure you do -> `return firebase....` to chain your promise.

Comment: if beta is synchronous, then, yes, that's how you do it, charlie won't run until beta returns - no change (other than the Promise constructor anti-pattern) is required

Comment: @Keith why is it redundant?  I know I could use `return firebase.database....` but then I'm worried that it'll resolve before the `.then()` completes.

Comment: @Badrush - no, the promise returned is the promise returned by `.then` - that's how chaining works

Comment: As @JaromandaX above says, it's chaining.  You should only ever need a promise constructor to convert a standard callback into a promise.   The more code you have that's using promises the less you should ever require `new Promise`..

Comment: by the way, when I say "no change required", I mean no change to your proposed solution

Comment: FYI, there is no such thing as a synchronous function that contains an asynchronous call.  If the function contains any asynchronous operation, then the whole function is asynchronous as it won't be done with its job until the asynchronous operation is done.

Comment: @Keith can you post your comment as an answer. I will test it out in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async func alpha(){
   beta(); //sync
   await charlie(); //sync but contains an async call
   delta(); // now this will only run after charlie() is done
}
func charlie(){
   // do some stuff

   //Make async call and return promise 
   return firebase.database.ref.once()

 }
```

`charlie()` should return a promise, `await` will wait untill `charlie()` finished.

Comment: Please do explain your answer